# Mvc rules and concepts

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

A view can have only one `@model Folder.ModelName` but what if I want to show data from two different tables in one view? How should I do this and what is the right way? For example, if I want to select all profits of the current user and to select all costs of the current user in the one view, then obviously this is 2 tables with 2 different models. Basically my question is, where can I find some rules and concepts for the `asp.net mvc` pattern?

Comment: create a model that has both models as members

Answer (score 2):

You would create something known as ViewModel. ViewModel can contain one or more entities, methods, additional fields, etc. You then pass this ViewModel to your View. For example,

```
namespace Sample
{
    public class ProfitCostViewModel
    {
        public Profit Profit { get; set; }
        public Cost Cost { get; set; }

        public decimal DoSomeCalculations()
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

In your Action, create an instance of this ViewModel class and initialize properties Profit and Cost. Then pass this object to the View. Inside of your view your can declare model like:

```
@model Sample.ProfitCostViewModel
```

and use it as

```
<p>Current profit or something: @Model.Profit.SomeProfitProperty</p>
<p>Sample cost: @Model.Profit.SomeCostProperty</p>
```

And that's how you would pass two or more entities as a model to your view.

UPDATE: You action could be something like:

```
public ActionResult YourAction()
{
    var profitCostVm = new ProfitCostViewModel();
    profitCostVm.Profit = LoadProfitFromSomewhere();
    profitCostCm.Cost = LoadCostFromSomewhere();

    return View(profitCostCm);
}
```

Comment: in my View i should @ProfitCostViewModel, but in action i don't understand what you mean please provide simple example like you did for Model class